# Are Oracle and MySQL ACID compliant?

Tags: mysql, oracle, acid

PostgreSQL claims one of they main features is ACID compliance. I have not managed to find clear statements regarding Oracle and MySQL on that.

Comment: Well can't speak for MySQL but oracle certainly is (unless you try to break it like putting commits in the middle of cursor) Tom Kyte has an excellent book called Expert Oracle Database Architecture that really gets into the nuts and bolts of everything.

Comment: MySql --> see this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html

Comment: I have been searching Oracle db web documentation and have not found anything mentioning that. Not in their features or specifications list. If it is not part of official specs - then how anyone can rely on that?

Comment: regarging mysql, your link says "adhere closely to the ACID model"  - so what exactly does it mean - is it ACID or not?

Comment: "All Oracle transactions obey the basic properties of a database transaction, known as ACID properties"  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT016

Comment: According to these slides from 2019 https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/slideshows/top-10-2019-databases.html only PostgreSQL and SQLite are ACID compliant